# Android Help Button setOnclickListener

Tags: android, android-button

My app works good but after assigning Button `bbtn` to `setOnClickListener` the app doesn't load on the Emulator and gives me the following errors :

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.Hawa.hawa_pro/.MainActivity }
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Code:

```
package com.Hawa.hawa_pro;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.content.res.Resources;


public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

private TabHost mTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bbtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    bbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,beauty.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Resources res= getResources();
    mTabHost =getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    //Home Tab
    intent= new Intent(this, Home.class);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home")
            .setIndicator("Home",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.homebtn))
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    //won tab

 intent= new Intent(this, About_wom.class);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("About_wom")
            .setIndicator("About Wom",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.aboutwombtn))
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

 intent= new Intent(this, Contact.class);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Contact")
            .setIndicator("Contact",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.contactbtn))
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
  }
```

Comment: This is not error. It says your current code's output is already loaded in your device/emulator. If you change or re build your code it will run again.

Comment: Force stop your App from Setting->App in your Emulator and then Run your Application .

Answer (score 1):

Exit current app on Emulator first, then run your app again :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a space anywhere in your code (in any file). Just Save the project and run. It will then go through the uploading and installing process again. This is the easiest way to go about it without actually changing any code that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Force stop your App from Setting in your Emulator & then Run.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your Android Application Project then it install .apk file on emulator, if first run the project then .apk file installs on emulator then if you run project again without any changes and your previous app is still on screen then it just gives this warning, No need to fear just do some changes in project then run again.